# My retail store credit card charges a fee after the balance is paid

Tags: united-states, credit-card

My retail store credit card charges me a $2.00 fee the month after I pay my balance in full. If I pay by the due date is this legal ?

Comment: Please add more details.  Does the card agreement indicate a monthly fee?

Comment: Which store is it?

Comment: Is this by any chance Macy's?

Comment: If they are doing it, it's almost certainly legal. If you don't like it, close the account.

Comment: Yes it it Macy's. They told me that interest starts accruing @ 12:01 a.m. the day(morning) after statements are created. So basically the consumer has 60 seconds to pay their balance in full without being hit with the $2.00 charge. I know of no other retailer that has this policy.

Answer (score 11):

Based on my research, I'm going to guess that the credit card in question is from Macy's.

Macy's credit cards feature a minimum $2.00 interest charge, and they apparently have a history of charging people this $2 interest charge monthly even after their bill is paid in full.

A [post on the Consumerist blog from 2010](https://consumerist.com/2010/03/09/macys-adds-monthly-2-educational-interest-charge-to-my-credit-card-bill/) reports that a reader was getting charged this monthly $2 interest charge.  Macy's customer service referred to it as "educational interest."

In 2011, [a user named Babble-on reported](http://www.complaintsboard.com/complaints/macys-colorado-c427935.html) that a similar thing happened to that user.  Babble-on speculated that it was due to interest being charged on a fraction of a penny left over on the account, and resulted in being charged the $2 minimum fee each month.

There are more recent complaints of this problem as well, with several users chiming in with similar stories this year on [Complaint Board](http://www.complaintboard.com/macy-039-s-credit-card-l221.html) and [CreditKarma](https://www.creditkarma.com/reviews/credit-card/single/id/macys-credit-card?pg=3&pgsz=25).

Based on the reports I've read, it appears you need to call their customer support and request that they remove this $2 charge.  After you get that straightened out, you may want to consider closing this account.

Comment: +1 for closing the account.  That seems like an absurd policy.